# Stretch \xrightarrow to fill available space

Tags: alignment

I am trying to typeset a solution to a system of equations like so:
[image: solution to system of equations]

Using `alignat` I was able to align the left ends of the arrows and the left edges of the column of matrices. All the arrows are of the type `\xrightarrow`. I would prefer the arrows to all be of the same length. Is there an easy way to stretch them to the width of their column?

Here is some example code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & 4 & 4 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 4 &-4 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
&\xrightarrow{R_3+R_1\mapsto R_3}
&&\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 5 & 5 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 4 &-4 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\\
%
&\xrightarrow{R_4+R_2\mapsto R_4}
&&\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 5 & 5 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 5 &-5 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\\
%
&\xrightarrow{R_3/5\mapsto R_3}
&&\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 5 &-5 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post a full compilable code?

Comment: one way to get the arrows to all be the same length would be to set all the modifiers (centered) in boxes of the same width.  but it would be easier to work with this if you posted a small compilable example with the code you already have.

Comment: I have added the code for part of the alignment. It won't give exactly the same output but it still illustrates the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose to define with `xparse`  an `\eqxrightarrow` command, where the main argument is nested in an `\eqmakebox` command, from the `eqparbox` package. To simplify typing, I also used the optional argument of `\xrightarrow` , so that you can group two different elementary operations ( inasmuch as they don't interact with each other). The last (optional) argument is the tag for the `\eqmakebox` commands, which defaults to `EO`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools, old-arrows}
\usepackage{eqparbox} %
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\eqxrightarrow}{o m O{EO}}{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\xrightarrow{\eqmakebox[#3]{$\scriptstyle #2$}}}%
{\xrightarrow[#1]{\eqmakebox[#3]{$\scriptstyle #2$}}}}

\begin{document}%O{EO}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{@{}rrrr|r@{}}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & 4 & 4 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 4 &-4 & 1
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}
&\eqxrightarrow[R_4+R_2\mapsto R_4]{R_3+R_1\mapsto R_3}
&&\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{@{}rrrr|r@{}}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 5 & 5 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 5 &-5 & 1
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}\\
&\eqxrightarrow{R_3/5\mapsto R_3}
&&\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{@{}rrrr|r@{}}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 5 &-5 & 1
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know this package. Thank you for have lead me to it.